# Basic quest on Twitter API user search and the relevance of results

Tags: search, twitter, relevance

Dear Stackoverflowianers,
Dear Twitter-Gurus,

This is just a basic question, waiting for a simple basic answere:

I do a user search by Twitter API with the following URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Hans%20Spitzer&page=1&count=10
```

The result looks like this: https://snap.apigee.com/1awu22I

Now my question: Why the Twitter API finds users with name "John Solo" and screen_name "Shock_Monster" or e.g. name "Vicente Durán Casas" and screen_name "vicdurcas" and even (the best) "SWR Nachrichten RP" with screen_name of "swrnewsrp".

At some of the search results there is no Hans Spitzer at all inside... Why this happens or "How to make a perfect search for relevant users"?

Thnx. so much for your answere in advance!

Best regards, Ingmar